# Filter function on a array cannot return the result the second time

Tags: angular

I have a service coming from `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`. I need to filter my service list on the basis of radio button clicked.

html:

```
<input type="radio" value="All"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioButtonValue"
  (change)="onRadioButtonSelectionChanged(e)" />All

<input type="radio" value="true"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioButtonValue" 
  (change)="onRadioButtonSelectionChanged(e)" />Completed True

<input type="radio" value="false"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioButtonValue" 
  (change)="onRadioButtonSelectionChanged($Event)" />Completed False
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let f of studentsfromapi | slice:0:10 | searchPipe:srchbytitle">
    <td>{{f.userId}}</td>
    <td><a [routerLink]="['/student-details', f.id]">{{f.id}}</a></td>

    <!--<td><a routerLink="['/student-details/{{f.id}}">{{f.id}}</a></td>-->
    <td>{{f.title}}</td>
    <td>{{f.completed}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

ts file:

```
selectedRadioButtonValue: string;
onRadioButtonSelectionChanged(e): any {
  e = this.selectedRadioButtonValue
  alert("hi"+ e);

  if (e.toLowerCase() === 'all') {
    console.log("studentsfromapi:::" + this.studentsfromapi);
    // return f.title.indexOf(args.toLowerCase()) > -1
    //return this.studentsfromapi.indexOf(e.toLowerCase()) > -1
  } else {
    // this._StudentHttpServService.getstudentHttpSrv()
    //   .subscribe((employeeData) =>
    //     this.studentsfromapi = employeeData );
    console.log(this.studentsfromapi.filter(x =>
      x.completed.toString() === e.toLowerCase()));
    this.studentsfromapi =
      this.studentsfromapi.filter(x =>
        x.completed.toString() === e.toLowerCase() && x.id < 5);
  }
}
```

It seems to work fine when i click on either 'completed true' radio or 'completed false' radio THE FIRST TIME, but when i click, say, 'completed false' radio AFTER clicking 'completed true' radio, my function searched from the list it got from the previous radio click, due to which i cannot return any completed false result when i click 'completed false' after 'completed true'. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="radio" value="All"  (change)="onRadioButtonSelectionChanged('all')" />All

<input type="radio" value="true"  (change)="onRadioButtonSelectionChanged('true')" />Completed True

<input type="radio" value="false" (change)="onRadioButtonSelectionChanged('false')" />Completed False
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let f of studentsfromapi | slice:0:10 | searchPipe:srchbytitle">
<td>{{f.userId}}</td>
<td><a [routerLink]="['/student-details', f.id]">{{f.id}}</a></td>

<!--<td><a routerLink="['/student-details/{{f.id}}">{{f.id}}</a></td>-->
<td>{{f.title}}</td>
<td>{{f.completed}}</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

on ts:

```
  onRadioButtonSelectionChanged(e):any{


        if(e=='all'){
    console.log("studentsfromapi:::"+this.studentsfromapi);
     // return f.title.indexOf(args.toLowerCase())>-1
     //return this.studentsfromapi.indexOf(e.toLowerCase())>-1

    }

    else{

      //this._StudentHttpServService.getstudentHttpSrv().subscribe((employeeData) => //this.studentsfromapi=employeeData );
      console.log(this.studentsfromapi.filter(x=>x.completed.toString()==e.toLowerCase()));
      this.studentsfromapi = this.studentsfromapi.filter(x=>x.completed.toString()==e.toLowerCase() && x.id<5 );

    }

      }
```